# MS Access: Can we use a date function inside the IN operator?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I am trying to create a crosstab query from a table:

```
ProductName | DateP    | Value |
Milk1       |1/1/2015  |      4|
Milk2       |1/1/2014  |      3|
Milk3       |1/1/2013  |      3|
```

So that the crosstab query results will look like below:

```
ProductName | 2014 | 2015 |
Milk1       |      |    4 |
Milk2       |    3 |      |
Milk3       |      |      |
```

So my query is:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(test.Value) AS Total
SELECT test.ProductName
FROM test
GROUP BY test.ProductName
PIVOT Year(test.DateP)
IN(Year(Now())-1, Year(Now())); ===> this line is the error its looking for missing parenthesis or square brackets but if I change that to IN(2014,2015) it's working fine
```

What I want is the year columns to be dynamic and at most 2 columns only will appear like if we are on the year 2016 now the columns should be 2015 and 2016 respectively.

I'm hoping for a back end part work around with this but, if I find none then I will use the front end trick I know to query this.

EDITED:
NOTE: The ProductName 'Milk3' should be displayed too, that is, even the product doesn't have a value for that year it should be displayed also. Gustav's solution below is almost right.

Comment: try adding another set of parenthesis: `IN((Year(Now())-1), Year(Now()));`. sometimes Access is stupid like that...

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(test.Value) AS Total
SELECT test.ProductName
FROM test
WHERE test.DateP 
    Between DateSerial(Year(Date())-1, 1, 1) 
    And DateSerial(Year(Date()), 12, 31)
GROUP BY test.ProductName
PIVOT Year(test.DateP)
```

which will utilize an index on DateP.

Comment: Some error on that query, missing operator in "Year(test.DateP)
WHERE test.DateP 
    Between DateSerial(Year(Date())-1, 1, 1) 
    And DateSerial(Year(Date()), 12, 31);" are you sure you can use where after PIVOT?

Comment: No, it should probably be stated after _FROM_ ... see edit.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that 'Milk3' should also be displayed as what I edited above, see edit, silly me. The query you gave almost had what I wanted though. So I'm guessing one should use the IN operator in this scenario.